# How C++ "searches" for functions or else if statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Let's say I have 200 functions in a C++ program. Every time I call one, how does the program finds the function? Is this a linear search? A binary search?

If a have an `if`/`else if`/.../`else` statment with 200 `else if` will the program search them one by one? If so how I can improve the performance here?

Comment: The branching depends on what the compiler wants to do with your code, branch prediction, which happens at runtime. Functions (non-class functions, in particular) are all handled at compile time, so there is no searching necessary at runtime. For class methods, sometimes the class hierarchy/inheritance needs to be inspected in order to resolve which _method_ to call.

Comment: C++ is a *compiled* language, not an interpreted one. The whole "searching for functions" bit is done *once* at compile time and the result then encoded in the binary. The program doesn't search for the functions every time it is run.

Answer (score 5):

In compiled binary file, a function call is just instruction `call` with address, where your function is located. So program doesn't need to find the function. It just already knows function's address and jumps to it.

For `else if` statements, your program just tests every condition. As you suggested in comment, switch may be an optimization is some cases but it is recommended (by me) not to rely on it. Use it only if it makes your code clearer.

Comment: The compiler knows the "distance" between the start of an `if` statement and the end.  The compiler will usually emit a *branch, or jump* instruction to the end of the `if` statement.  This is computed by adding the *distance* of the code in the statement block to the present value of the program counter (or some processors can perform a jump using a relative distance, such as 100 statements forward).

Answer (score 1):

if-else if-else conditions are evaluated one by one, until a condition is matches. You may be able to optimize a specific usecase, but in the general form, you'd have to check them one by one.

Comment: Is using a switch a better alternative?

Comment: The `switch` is a specific form of the `if-else` ladder.  For example, the `switch` doesn't work with strings in C++.  Also, you may want to consider lookup tables as well.